# ng-switch in custom angular directive breaks two way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I created my custom directive to encapsulate an uib-datepicker-popup:

```
'use strict';
angular.module( 'frontendApp' )
.directive( 'inputDate', function(){

var controller = function(){

  var vm = this;

  function init() {
    vm.formats = [ 'dd.MMMM yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate' ];
    vm.format = vm.formats[ 0 ];
    vm.altInputFormats = [ 'M!/d!/yyyy' ];

    vm.dateOptions = {
      datepickerMode: 'day',
      formatYear: 'yy',
      maxDate: new Date(),
      minDate: new Date( 1900, 1, 1 ),
      startingDay: 1
    };

    vm.datepicker = {
      opened: false
    };
  };

  init();

  vm.showDatePicker = function(){
    vm.datepicker.opened = true;
  };
};

var template = '<div ng-switch on="readonly" >' +
    '<div ng-switch-when="true" class="form-control" readonly>' +
      '<div readonly name="readonlyText">{{ngModel | date : \'d.MMMM yyyy\'}}</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div ng-switch-default class="input-group">' +
      '<input class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.format}}" ng-model="ngModel" ng-model-options="{timezone:\'UTC\'}" is-open="vm.datepicker.opened" datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" ng-required="true" show-button-bar="false" alt-input-formats="vm.altInputFormats" />' +
      '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.showDatePicker()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>' +
      '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>';


return{
  controller: controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  bindToController: true,
  template: template,
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope           :true,
  require:'ngModel',
  link: function( scope, element, attrs, ngModel ){
    // Bring in changes from outside:
    scope.$watch( 'ngModel', function(){
      if( ngModel ) {
        scope.$eval( attrs.ngModel + ' = ngModel' );
      }
    } );

    // Send out changes from inside:
    scope.$watch( attrs.ngModel, function( val ){
      if( val ) {
        scope.ngModel = val;
      }
    } );

    if( attrs.readonly === 'true' ) {
      scope.readonly = true;
    }
  }
};
```

} );

The html part then is:

```
<input-date ng-model="form.flight.date"></input-date>
```

The problem: if the popup shows up, scope.ngModel is initialized correctly from attrs.ngModel. I had a log inside the watcher that showed me that watching attrs.ngModel works perfecly, but watching 'ngModel' or scope.ngModel does only work until i use the datepicker. It works perfectly as long as the datepicker is not triggered.
Just discovered that it works perfectly if i remvoe the 
"ng-switch-default". Replacing it with ng-show/ng-hide makes the directive work completely as expected.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is absolutely correct. When you use structural directives like `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, `ng-repeat` etc. it creates a new scope and **copies all attributes** of the parent scope. Your model is a primitive (string), so it is fully copied to the new scope and changed within this scope without propagation to the parent one.

What you can do is:

1. Use object instead of string to pass the `ng-model`, what I personally find here very awkward
2. Use `ng-model` from controller object and not from the scope

Going on with the second approach: you already use `bindToController` and an isolated scope by `scope: true`, so just instead of tracking the model with watcher bind it to the controller:

```
return {
  bindToController: true,
  scope: {
    ngModel: '='
  },
  ...
```

so ideally you won't even need your link function and in the template instead of

```
'<div readonly name="readonlyText">{{ngModel | date : \'d.MMMM yyyy\'}}</div>'
```

use

```
'<div readonly name="readonlyText">{{vm.ngModel | date : \'d.MMMM yyyy\'}}</div>'
```

Why `ng-hide` still works? It does not create a new scope.

Comment: Thanks, approach number two works perfectly and nicely shrinked my link function :)